# Get n last records and change particular columns on them

Tags: bash, awk

I have file like this

```
1      2      "45554323"      p      b  
2      2      "34534567"      f      a  
3      3      "76546787"      u      b  
2      4      "56765435"      f      a  
*      a  
0      b
```

I want delete `a`, `b` from two last Records in `END{}` section

Result:

```
1      2      "45554323"      p      b  
2      2      "34534567"      f      a  
3      3      "76546787"      u      b  
2      4      "56765435"      f      a  
*        
0
```

How can I get n last lines and change fields on them with awk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way using any awk:

```
awk -v count=$(wc -l <file.txt) 'NR > count - 2 { $2 = "" }1' file.txt
```

Results:

```
1      2      "45554323"      p      b  
2      2      "34534567"      f      a  
3      3      "76546787"      u      b  
2      4      "56765435"      f      a  
* 
0
```

Or to do `awk` operations for all records except 2 last lines of input file as a shell script, try `./script.sh file.txt`. Contents of `script.sh`:

```
command=$(awk -v count=$(wc -l <"$1") 'NR <= count - 2 { $2 = "" }1' "$1"
echo -e "$command"
```

Results:

```
1  "45554323" p b
2  "34534567" f a
3  "76546787" u b
2  "56765435" f a
*      a  
0      b
```

Answer (score 3):

If you know the value of `n` - the line number *after* which you want to delete the last item on the line/colum (here `4`) this will work:

```
awk '{if (NR>4) NF=NF-1}1' data.txt
```

will give:

```
1      2      "45554323"      p      b  
2      2      "34534567"      f      a  
3      3      "76546787"      u      b  
2      4      "56765435"      f      a  
*
0
```

`NF = NF -1` makes awk think there is one less field on the line than there is, which is how it doesn't display the last column/item on the line once that condition is met. `NR` refers to the current line number in the file being read.

awk can't know the number of lines in a file unless it goes through it once, or is given that information (e.g., `wc -l`).  An alternative approach would be to save the last `n` lines in a buffer (sort of a sliding window/tape-delay type analogy, you are always printing `n` lines behind) and then process the final `n` lines in the `END` block.

Comment: @levon..the number of records is variable because my file is a result of other awk operation and my two last lines changes in this operation but i want delete new columns created in two last records

Comment: @mohammadreshad If you know the number of lines in the file (from your previous operation) than you ought to be able to change the condition to `if (NO_OF_LINE - 2 > NR)` or something along those lines. awk won't be able to know the number of lines unless it goes through the file once, or you provide it with that information. Maybe `sed` could possibly do this more easily.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly answer your question but it produces the output you require:

```
$ gawk '{if (NF < 3) print $1; else print}' input.txt
1      2      "45554323"      p      b
2      2      "34534567"      f      a
3      3      "76546787"      u      b
2      4      "56765435"      f      a
*
0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat file
1      2      "45554323"      p      b
2      2      "34534567"      f      a
3      3      "76546787"      u      b
2      4      "56765435"      f      a
*      a
0      b

$ awk 'BEGIN{ARGV[ARGC++]=ARGV[ARGC-1]} NR==FNR{nr++; next} FNR>(nr-2) {NF--} 1' file
1      2      "45554323"      p      b
2      2      "34534567"      f      a
3      3      "76546787"      u      b
2      4      "56765435"      f      a
*
0
```

or if you don't mind manually specifying the file name twice:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{nr++; next} FNR>(nr-2) {NF--} 1' file file
```